# react native crashlytics crashlytics().crash() not crashing

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have the following versions for react native and react native firebase crashlytics.

package.json:

- react-native: 0.66.4
- @react-native-firebase/app: 14.2.4
- @react-native-firebase/crashlytics: ^14.2.4

android project gradle:

- com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1
  android app gradle:
- implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

According to the [document](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage#crash-attributes) running this line should create a crash.

```
crashlytics().crash();
```

This is only working on a release build. However, when I run the app on metro by `react-native run-android`, this does nothing, it did not create a crash. What can I do to make it crash by running the above line in metro environment?

Comment: I've only done this in ios but what worked for me was to turn the build to `release` and then turn off  `debug executable`. Maybe that will help

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My app is not crashing

Answer (score 1):

i found [this](https://invertase.io/blog/react-native-firebase-crashlytics-configuration) solution its working for me

Create a firebase.json file in the root directory of your react-native app, with these Crashlytics-related keys set to these specific values:

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_disable_auto_disabler": true,
    "crashlytics_auto_collection_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_is_error_generation_on_js_crash_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_javascript_exception_handler_chaining_enabled": true
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck for me . Any other helpful something ?

Comment: While connected to metro, after this, i was able to crash the app using crashlytics().crash() from react-native-firebase.  However, I am not seeing the crash appear in the firebase console yet, although it does now show "app detected, waiting for crash".  I will wait another day and see if it appears.

Comment: @JeffPadgett how did it go